# Configuring Haskell's default directory for project creation

Tags: haskell, configuration, directory, project, haskell-stack

As someone who is new to Haskell, I was setting up my text-editors, environments etc. when I found that any new projects I created using the command-line:

```
stack new my-project new-template
```

would always be stored in the directory:

```
C:\Users\username
```

This isn't  ideal, and I wondered if it was possible to change the default directory somehow (this also happens when I clone projects from GitLab).

My operating system is Windows 10 (64 bit) and I have installed Haskell 8.4.3 along with Haskell stack and Git.

Any potential solution would be greatly appreciated; please do ask for more information if it's needed.

Thanks!

Comment: If you `cd` into different directory and invoke the about command, does that still result in `C:\Users\username` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you current directory is `C:\Users\username`

I think the simple solution is just `cd` to your preferred directory.
For example if have a project directory named `project` in drive `D` then
`cd D:\project` followed by `stack new my-project new-template`.

If you use `cmd.exe`, then you must type `d:` first.

Comment: `cd` doesn't change the current drive by default. `cd /d d:\project` might work better.